# Does jquery 3.6.1 support jquery-validation 1.19.5?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The project that I am working on uses jquery version 3.6.1 and jquery-validate version 1.15.0 along with jquery-validate-unobtrusive version 3.2.11 .

I want to update my jquery-validate version as its outdated

I looked at the documentation and found this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INt7T.png)

However I am not able to come to a conclusion . Can someone please help me here ?

I want to know which jquery-validate version should I choose so that Its compatible with both of my existing jquery 3.6.1 version and jquery-validate-unobtrusive version 3.2.11

Comment: Can't you just try them?

Comment: I am not sure of the impact it would create if I go ahead an upload it in the cdn and the repo so I just want to be sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your requested info in package.json:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.7 || ^2.0 || ^3.1"
}
```

so the short answer is yes. other than that you need to give it a try to it.

Comment: I used  jquery  validation version 1.19.3 as it was the most stable one from the latest versions, tested it and works fine . Thanks for your inputs !